How can i Resize text and add Icon to RexUI panel?
here im trying to create a scrollable panel by creating this small panel
const COLOR_PRIMARY = 0x4e342e;

var CreatePanel = function (scene) {
    var panel = scene.rexUI.add.sizer({
        width: 100,
        orientation: 'y',
        space: { item: 4 }
    })

    for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        var name = `item-${i}`;
        var label = scene.rexUI.add.label({
            height: 350,
            width: 1500,
            background: scene.rexUI.add.roundRectangle({
                color: COLOR_PRIMARY
            }),
            
            text: scene.add.text(
                10, 
                10, 
               
                'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the pinting'),
            name: name,
        })
        panel.add(label, { expand: true });
    }

    return panel;
}

but i dont know how to add an image as icon, and how to resize text inside panel.
i added setWordWrapWidth but when i type long word i cannot wrap anymore

Please help!

Depending on your usecase you can use setFontSize (link to documentation) or setScale on the text GameObject (link to documentation).
For the Image / Icon, simply use the property icon (check out the plugin documentation for details).
Here a short Demo:


document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

class ExampleScene extends Phaser.Scene {
    constructor() {
        super('ExampleScene');
    }

    preload() { 
        this.load.scenePlugin({
            key: 'rexuiplugin',
            url: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rexrainbow/phaser3-rex-notes/master/dist/rexuiplugin.min.js',
            sceneKey: 'rexUI'
        });
    }
    create() {
    
      let graphics  = this.make.graphics();
      graphics.fillStyle(0xffffff);
      graphics.fillRect(0, 0, 10, 10);
      graphics.generateTexture('icon', 10, 10);

      var panel = this.rexUI.add.sizer({
            x: 10, y: 10,
            width: 300, 
            height: 100,
            orientation: 1
        }).setOrigin( 0 );

      panel.add(this.rexUI.add.label({
            x: 0, 
            y: 0,
            text: this.add.text( 0,  0, 'Label 1 Normal Text'),
            icon: this.add.image(0, 0, 'icon'),
            squareFitIcon: true,
            space: {
                left: 10, right: 10, top: 10, bottom: 10,
                icon: 10, text: 10,
            }
        }),  { proportion: 1, expand: true });
      panel.add(this.rexUI.add.label({
            x: 0, 
            y: 40,
            text: this.add.text( 0, 0, 'Label 2 18px Text')
              .setFontSize('18px'),
            icon: this.add.image(0, 0, 'icon'),
            squareFitIcon: true,
            space: {
                left: 10, right: 10, top: 10, bottom: 10,
                icon: 10, text: 10,
            }
        }),  { proportion: 1, expand: true });
        panel.add(this.rexUI.add.label({
            x: 0, 
            y: 80,
            text: this.add.text( 0, 0, 'Label 3 Scale x1.25 Text')
              .setScale(1.25),
            icon: this.add.image(0, 0, 'icon'),
            squareFitIcon: true,
            space: {
                left: 10, right: 10, top: 10, bottom: 10,
                icon: 10, text: 10,
            }
        }),  { proportion: 1, expand: true });
        
        panel.layout();
    }
}

var config = {
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    scene: [ ExampleScene ],
    parent: 'phaser-example',
    banner: false
}; 

new Phaser.Game(config);
console.clear();
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
<div id="phaser-example"></div>



Update for Question from Comment:
As mentioned in the comment there are many options to solve this. The easy on is to "nest" sizer.
Short Demo:
This demo is based on this example, in the example one icon is used, I altered it so that two icons can be displayed, in the properties icon1 and icon2.


const Random = Phaser.Math.Between;

class Demo extends Phaser.Scene {
    constructor() {
        super({ key: 'examples' });
    }

    preload() {
        this.load.scenePlugin({
            key: 'rexuiplugin',
            url: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rexrainbow/phaser3-rex-notes/master/dist/rexuiplugin.min.js',
            sceneKey: 'rexUI'
        });    
    }

    create() {
    
        this.createTexureForIcons();
    
        var x = config.width/2,
            y = config.height/2,
            minWidth = 300,
            minHeight = undefined,
            table = {
                title: 'Title/Title/Title',
                data: [{
                        icon1Texture: 'icon1',
                        icon2Texture: 'icon2',
                        name: 'AAA',
                        content: 'Hello',
                    },
                    {
                        icon1Texture: 'icon1',
                        icon2Texture: 'icon3',
                        name: 'BBBB',
                        content: 'World',
                    },
                ]
            };

        var sizer = getTable(this, x, y, minWidth, minHeight, table);
        sizer.drawBounds(this.add.graphics(), 0xff0000);
    }
    
    createTexureForIcons(){        
        let graphics  = this.make.graphics();
        graphics.fillStyle(0xffffff);
        graphics.fillRect(0, 0, 10, 10);
        graphics.generateTexture('icon1', 10, 10);
        graphics.fillStyle(0xff0000);
        graphics.fillRect(0, 0, 10, 10);
        graphics.generateTexture('icon2', 10, 10);
        graphics.fillStyle(0x00ff00);
        graphics.fillRect(0, 0, 10, 10);
        graphics.generateTexture('icon3', 10, 10);
        graphics.fillStyle(0x0000ff);
        graphics.fillRect(0, 0, 10, 10);
        graphics.generateTexture('icon3', 10, 10);
    }
}

var getRow = function (scene, data) {

    var icon1 = scene.add.image(0, 0, data.icon1Texture);
    var icon2 = scene.add.image(0, 0, data.icon2Texture);
    var nameLabel = scene.add.text(0, 0, data.name, {
        fontSize: '24px',
        color: 'white'
    });
    var contentLabel = scene.add.text(0, 0, data.content, {
        fontSize: '24px',
        color: 'white'
    });
    var sizer = scene.rexUI.add.sizer({
            orientation: 'x',
        })
        .add(icon1, {expand: true, fitRatio: true})
        .add(icon2, {expand: true, fitRatio: true})
        .add(nameLabel, 2, 'left')
        .add(contentLabel, 5, 'left');
    return sizer;
}

var getTable = function (scene, x, y, width, height, table) {
    var title = scene.add.text(0, 0, table.title, {
        fontSize: '32px',
        color: 'white'
    });

    var sizer = scene.rexUI.add.sizer(x, y, width, height, {
            orientation: 'y',
        })
        .add(title);

    var padding = {
        top: 10,
        //bottom: 10,
        left: 10,
        right: 10,
    }
    var data = table.data;
    for (var i = 0, cnt = data.length; i < cnt; i++) {
        sizer.add(getRow(scene, data[i]), 0, 'left', padding);
    }
    sizer.layout();
    return sizer;
}

var config = {
    width: 510,
    height: 180,
    scene: Demo
};

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>




Thank you so much. Can i ask another question, when i try to upsize text, my panel width  auto get bigger. Do you know how to avoid it?

It really all depends on your usecase, of the top of my head  you could limit the size of the label, by wraping long text, with this function setWordWrapWidth link to dokumentation, link this it panel shouldn't  expand, but the text would be in multiple lines.

thank you so much, i edited my question can you give me another answer. thank you so much and sorry for my broken english

Well the problem is the phaser can't wrap if there are no white spaces, but you could use rexUI plugin label feature / property  wrapText, you would have to set it to 2, this breaks up the text even without whitespace.

thank you so much. I work as i want to be. you are literally a live saver

can you help me how to add multiplies icon in one label, i read rexUi docs several time but cannot find how to add 3 or 4 icons instead of one

I think, the normal sizer can't add multiple icons, but you can try using the plugin gridSizer. link to the documentation.  On the top of this page there are some example,. Or you could try nesting sizers, but this will get pretty complicated. Or create your own custom image class (that outputs/merges multiple images). The best way depends on your specific usecase.

Sorry for bother you again, but i cant find a way to add icon to a sizer. Can you be more specific

@ViễnThôngĐiệntử I updated my answer with a solution, I hope this helps.

@ViễnThôngĐiệntử I updated my answer so that it works for images. btw.:  You should create new Question, rather than asking followup question in the comments (If it's a new question).  Since on StackOverflow should be questions/answer should be focused (Article on SO Questions).
